# Copy a vertical list and paste horizontally with offsets in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, offset

I want to copy the list `PoSend.Range("B" & a).Value` (which is a list until the last row), horizontally on sheet "Exprt" with an offset of three between each value

```vb
Dim Exprt As Worksheet
Set Exprt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO&Drawings")

For a = 9 To PoSend_LR

    PoSend_LR = PoSend.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    POinput = Left(PoSend.Range("B9"), Len(PoSend.Range("B9")) - 14)

    If Not IsEmpty(PoSend.Range("B9").Value) Then
    
    End If

    For a = 9 To PoSend_LR

        Dim mylink As String
        FileNameLong = PoSend.Range("B" & a).Value
        FileName = Left(FileNameLong, Len(FileNameLong) - 16)
        FullPath = PoSend.Range("E7") & "\" & FileName & "\" & FileNameLong
    
        Exprt.Range("B7").Offset(0, 3).Value = FileName
```

`Filename`is a string which contains each line from my `PoSend.Range("B" & a).Value` list. I'd like to paste each `filename` in `Exprt.Range("B7").Value` with an offset of three per pasted value.

Comment: I cannot understand anything from your question... What does "'''the wrong one" comment mean? What is `Exprt`? Another sheet? If so, what connection between the question title and the mentioned last code line should exist? Your code tries copying a string... What "loop" are you talking about?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would help a lot if you show us your data and the expected outcome. Reading [ask] and [repro] will take some time but will help you to improve your question. You should spend this time so that we, who want to help you, don't waste time on unclear requirements.

Comment: Hello @FaneDuru apologies for not being totally clear on this issue. You're right ```Exprt``` is in-fact another sheet. In summary, I'm trying to make a loop for every value in the list of```("B" & a).value``` to be pasted horizontally onto the sheet ```exprt``` Apologies about the code not being massivley informative, this is only a snapshot

Comment: It is completely unclear what you (specifically) want. What do you expect from `Exprt.Range("B7").Offset(0, 3).Value = FileName`?  If you want to copy/transpose the range `"B9:B" & PoSend_LR` no need of any iteration. But I cannot see any attempt to do something in this direction...

Comment: Consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73191889/edit) to clarify it. For one, it would be useful to know what it is you are trying to accomplish (a screencap of sample data and the expected outcome would probably help)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad hi, thanks for your recomendation, I have edited my question, hopefuly this is much clearer

Comment: @FaneDuru I've set ```Filename``` as a string of each line in my ```PoSend.Range("B" & a).Value``` list. Id like to paste each value of  ```filename``` (as it goes down my list) horizontally in page ```Exprt``` with an offset of 3 between each ```filename```

Comment: What "each value", lf it is a value of a cell? Please, edit your question and show us a picture with what you have and another one showing what you want obtaining. In a way to see the rows and columns headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best guess:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim Exprt As Worksheet, PoSend As Worksheet, c As Range, cDest As Range
    Dim Filename As String, FullPath As String, FileNameLong As String
    
    Set Exprt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO&Drawings")
    Set PoSend = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Send") 'eg...
    
    Set cDest = Exprt.Range("B7") 'starting destination
    'loop down from row 9 to last row in ColB
    For Each c In PoSend.Range("B9", PoSend.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Cells
        FileNameLong = c.Value
        If Len(FileNameLong) > 0 Then
            Filename = Left(FileNameLong, Len(FileNameLong) - 16)
            FullPath = PoSend.Range("E7") & "\" & Filename & "\" & FileNameLong
            cDest.Value = FullPath
            Set cDest = cDest.Offset(0, 3) 'next destination cell
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Smashed it Tim, thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for